# React JS Warning: React.createElement:

Tags: reactjs

I am learning reactjs and I am getting errors when executing the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Tutorial</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/react-15.0.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/reactrouter-2.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/babel-core-5.6.16-browser.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/marked-0.3.5.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="app20"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="scripts/example.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

I am using react router to see how the menu works. index.js is classnames js of jedwatson and example.js contains code as below

    var Home = React.createClass({
       render() {
          return (    
             <div>
                <h1>Home...</h1>
             </div>
          );
       }
    });'

    var About = React.createClass({
       render() {
          return (
             <div>
                <h1>About...</h1>
             </div>
          );
       }
    });

    var Contact = React.createClass({
       render() {
          return (
             <div>
                <h1>Contact...</h1>
             </div>
          );
       }
    });



    var App20 = React.createClass({
       render() {
          return (
             <div>
                <ul>
                   <li><ReactRouter.Link to="/home">Home</ReactRouter.Link></li>
                   <li><ReactRouter.Link to="/about">About</ReactRouter.Link></li>
                   <li><ReactRouter.Link to="/contact">Contact</ReactRouter.Link></li>
                </ul>

               {this.props.children}
             </div>
          );
       }
    });


    ReactDOM.render((<ReactRouter history = {ReactRouter.browserHistory}>
                        <ReactRouter.Route path = "/" component = {App20}>
                        <ReactRouter.IndexRoute component = {Home} />
                        <ReactRouter.Route path = "home" component = {Home} />
                        <ReactRouter.Route path = "about" component = {About} />
                        <ReactRouter.Route path = "contact" component = {Contact} />
                        </ReactRouter.Route>
                    </ReactRouter>), document.getElementById('app20'));
```

This should render a menu with sections "about", "home", "contact" which are mapped by a `react-router` implementation. When clicking on one of the menu items the respective component should be rendered below the menu.

But I am getting the following warning...

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, 
>        boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or 
>        a ReactClass (for composite components).

And this error...

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in 
>        components) or a class/function (for composite components) but 
>        got: object.

I would appreciate if you are able to help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Perhaps a shorter code will be easier for you and anyone trying to help to see the issue more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

You have a small typo. :)

```
    ReactDOM.render((<ReactRouter.Router history={ReactRouter.browserHistory}>
                    <ReactRouter.Route path = "/" component = {App20}>
                    <ReactRouter.IndexRoute component = {Home} />
                    <ReactRouter.Route path = "home" component = {Home} />
                    <ReactRouter.Route path = "about" component = {About} />
                    <ReactRouter.Route path = "contact" component = {Contact} />
                    </ReactRouter.Route>
                </ReactRouter.Router>), document.getElementById('app20'));
```

You were missing the `<ReactRouter.Router ...` part, you just had `<ReactRouter ...`.

Also, there is an extra `'` after your Home component:

```
                 <h1>Home...</h1>
         </div>
      );
   }
});'
```

Comment: many many thanks how can i make such a silly mistake you made my day. Now the code is working. I had an idea there must be some typo error i tried for 2/3 hours but failed and you solved it in seconds. I appreciate your help very much

Comment: No problem! :) Good luck on your journey with React.  Its super fun so keep at it! :)

Comment: When you start to feel more comfortable with React and have an IDE set up try looking into a tool such as `eslint` which helps to identify errors.  I'm not sure if it would have picked up the `ReactRouter.Router` issue, but the loose `'` certainly would have been seen.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me i will surely follow your advice. The ' error occurred while typing in  stackoverflow question it was not there in my original code.